# Express Emphasis without using Italics or Underline

Tags: phrases, expressions, emphasis

Are there any methods to express emphasis without using italics or underline? I find that there are many cases where formatting does not allow italics, even if emphasis would add to the text greatly.

I mean, *seriously*.

Comment: Um, **bold**? That was even available in the days of mechanical typewriters.

Comment: Well, there's always the option of bracketing the word in *single* or **double** asterisks, but for some reason that doesn't always work the way one might expect.

Comment: @HotLicks I believe you mean (in a markdown-preventive way) \*single\* or \*\*double\*\* asterisks?

Comment: Yep, but like I said, it doesn't always seem to work. ;)

Comment: Not that I know, but we !need! something. It ought to be !simple!, easy to understand at a !glance!, and typographically !straightforward!.

Comment: You can make do with <em>plain</em> ASCII when addressing the {\em right} audience.

Comment: Why should I make 'em plain when they're already plain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using italics just to hammer something across is like a joke that comes with its own laugh track: a sign of weakness.

A writer skilled in the craft expresses emphasis through variation in vocabulary, phrasing,  structure, and length. This is the best way.

Those of lesser skill ROUTINELY TURN TO ALL CAPITALS WHEN THEY WANT TO YELL AT YOU, BUT THIS IS HARDER TO READ AND GENERALLY CONSIDERED RUDE!!!!!!!!!!!